# vscode how to format vue file to comply with eslint rules

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

bascially what I want is the **consistency** between:

- how vscode format my .vue file
- how eslint checker scan my .vue file when I run `npm run ....` to start the server or build the target

currently I format my document in vscode and then run `npm run dev`, eslint checker will raise lots of warnings and errors, it seems that their foramting/linting rules come from different source, I haven't figure out a way to make them use the same rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, install these extensions:

- [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur)
- [ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)
- [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)

Then write these settings in your `settings.json`:

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  }
}
```